# Get bitfield from permissions_new

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How could I get the old/new bitfield from permissions_new?

```
[
   { key: 'permissions', old: 1880015056, new: 1880015040 },
   { key: 'permissions_new', old: '1880015056', new: '1880015040' }
]
```

That's the logs from

```
const entry = await newRole.guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: 'ROLE_UPDATE'}).then(audit => audit.entries.first())
console.log(entry.changes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const changes = [
   { key: 'permissions', old: 1880015056, new: 1880015040 },
   { key: 'permissions_new', old: '1880015056', new: '1880015040' }
];

const permissions_new = changes.find(({key}) => key == 'permissions_new');

console.log(`old: ${permissions_new.old}`);
console.log(`new: ${permissions_new.new}`);
```